# Existence of mixed Nash equilibrium if 2 pure Nash equilibia are present

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Let's have a normal game, where there are 2 pure Nash Equilibria. Is the presence of 2 pure NE a guarantee that there also exists a non-pure equilibrium?

Answer (score 0):

Not always, but often.  Consider the following game:

$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
  & L & R \\ \hline
T & 1,1 & 0,0 \\ \hline
B & 0,0 & 0,0 \\ \hline
  \end{array} $$

There are precisely two pure-strategy equilibria: $\{T,L\}$ and $\{B,R\}$.  In particular, note that there is no mixed strategy equilibrium as non-degenerate mixture between the two actions (of either player) induces the other to always play a pure strategy (either $T$ or $L$ depending on the player).

This is, however, an exception rather than the rule. You'd be right if you suspected that the above was somehow due to there being a 'lot of ties' in payoffs.  You can generally, for fixed agents/action sets, consider the 'space of games' as a vector in some euclidean space that determines the payoffs (the above might be considered the vector $(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^8$).

The below is a classical theorem due to Wilson/Harsanyi and others in various contexts.

> **Theorem**: Fix a finite player set and finite action sets for these players.  Then for an open, dense, subset of the space of games of full Lebesgue measure, the set of Nash equilibria is both finite and odd.